# The view app.views.services didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have looked for an answer and all I can find are answers related to forms. I haven't seen anything related to a model object. I have a model called PanelType and I am trying to loop through every object to display relevant information pertaining to each panel type on a html template. I have created 3 PanelType objects through the admin page, so there is not "None". I believe I have this setup correctly but it's returning an error of returning None objects. I'd appreciate any help.

models.py

```
class PanelType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=150, default='')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    description = models.TextField('Description', null=True, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(
        'Date Created', auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    display = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    image = models.ImageField('Panel Image', null=True, blank=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("model_detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug or self.slug != slugify(self.name):
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

views.py

```
def services(request):
    context = {'panels': PanelType.objects.all()}
    render(request, 'app/services.html', context)
```

html

```
<div class="service-container">
    {% for panel in panels %}
      <div class="card">
        <div class="serviceBx" data-text="{{panel.name}}">
          <img src="{{panel.image.url}}" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="service-content">
          <div>
            <h3>{{panel.name}}</h3>
            <p>{{panel.description}}</p>
            <a href="#">Get Quote</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to *return* the *result* of the `render(…)` function:

```
def services(request):
    context = {'panels': PanelType.objects.all()}
    # ↓ return the HttpResponse
    return render(request, 'app/services.html', context)
```

Comment: laughing at myself...how did I miss that???? Thank you lol